# Turntable Circuit

Tags: motor, switches

I have a 33 rpm turntable and I would like to put a switch in it to play 45 rpm records. I don't know where to start. I would appreciate some help with which electronic components I'll have to buy.

Comment: Question - does the turntable have a fine speed control?

Comment: Actually not. It just plays whenever I put its 'arm' in the record.

Comment: How about designing gears to achieve your output?

Comment: Right. That means it's synced to line frequency. It means that you would need to drive the motor with 110 VAC at about 82 Hz. You may find that a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

If the turntable has originally only 33 RPM, then it's probably not that easy. You will have to generate the motor excitation for 45 RPM. If the motor is AC, this means that you will have to generate the AC of the corresponding frequency. Given that 45 is 36% more than 33, you will also probably have to generate that much extra voltage because of the higher inductance.

Most (older) multi-RPM tables change speed mechanically (difference diameters).

If the motor is more modern (maybe a small DC motor) you might be lucky... So first check if the motor is connected directly to the mains or not (unplug it first :)

Comment: I see. I will probably have to buy old circuits on ebay.
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Hugo.L I would suggest to make this mechanically. Probably you will need to move some parts inside. A [transmission belt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belt_%28mechanical%29) might be the easiest to do.